# (Animation Nodes) How to make a wave-like sound visualizer?

Tags: animation-nodes, audio

I figured out that I can make cool sound visualizer using the animation nodes addon.
Can I make a Wave-like sound visualizer with a plane using AN ?

I want it to looks like this (If possible ^^)

-> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtD5UQE5Xj0

-> [image: I want it to looks like this]

Edit: Is it possible to drive the vertices of the plane with the music ?

Thanks for reading !

- A.C

Comment: I already seen this. But I want a plane to move like a wave, not cubes :/. I want it to looks like this (But with a square plane):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtD5UQE5Xj0

Comment: Maybe combine with sverchok, [like this](http://blendersushi.blogspot.com.au/2017/01/ansv-sound-wave-perlin-noise.html)